# How to access the last word from word within a list of query

Tags: android

I have a list of items queried from my database. This list has two words in each item, the two words are separated by a space. I now want to get access to only the last word after the space.

This the query from my database

```
public  List<String> getList(){
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LIST;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> row = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    if (cursor .moveToFirst()) {
         ;
        do {
            String listName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ITEM_A));

            array.add(listName);



        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    return array;
}
```

Accessing the items from the query

```
List<String> m = new ArrayList<String>();
    m = dbHelper.getList();


 System.out.println(m);
```

This gives the below output

```
[itemOA AITEME,itemOD BITEMD,itemOC CITEMS, itemOB DTEM]
```

I however wants to get the last words of the list,

```
   [AITEME, BITEMD, CITEMS ,DTEM]
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could restructure your code to save from having to do this, but:

```
String substr = myString.substring(startIndex);
```

Will work as long as you always have a known starting point (if it's always going to start with "itemOA" or 6 characters + a single whitespace)